# Drawing on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, opengl-es

Hello kind computing people,

Okay this is super broad, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

I've made an iPhone app using the Speak Here example project. The app works great, but now I want to use the equalizer bar independent of the actual audio input (i.e. to make it into a 'Loading Bar'). The thing is the Audio argument used to feed data into the graphics code seems to be quite intermeshed with the structure of how the graphics are created. I've been hacking around for quite a while, but I can't help feel like a cat chasing it's tail

Any advice on how to approach this? Anybody have any experience doing this?

I'll take any help I can get, including questions that may help me narrow down what I need to do.

---

**EDIT 1**

In particular I want to do some animations while there is NO input to the mic or output to the speaker i.e. when the argument to lvl_meter is NIL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both LevelMeter and GLLevelMeter look to be pretty reusable -- neither one has any ivars that's specifically audio-related.

That said, the code is from 2008-2009, so it may not reflect the best way to do things now. Also, it looks like it should be pretty easy to roll your own level meter. Have you tried that, and if so, what didn't work?